# Update Listview item and get values using BaseAdapter Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have a listview of that have multiple items.I want to update the items value on click of button and want to get the the values of all the items on click of the button.But i am unable to do that.Please help me to get this functionality

**Activity code**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_ItemValue);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_iween_booking_page);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.passengerList);

            showPassengerListView(passengerList);

        }

    getValue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(){


            }else{
                //Here i have to get all the value of the listview items in a array
            } 

        }
    });


    }

    private void showPassengerListView(final String[] passengerList) {

        listView.setAdapter(new PassengerListUpdate(passengerList));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }
    public void passengerInformationPopup(final String[] passengerList, final int position) {
        final Dialog dialog= new Dialog(MainActivity.this,R.style.Dialog_Fullscreen);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.passenger_details_dialog); 
        dialog.show();

        setValueDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                isSuccess= true;

                if(isSuccess){
                    dialog.cancel();
                    //Here i Have to Update the item at position with some value
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void goBack(View v) {
        finish();
    }

    class PassengerListUpdate extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] ItemValue;

        public PassengerListUpdate(String[] text) {
            ItemValue = text;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return ItemValue.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View vi;
            vi = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            TextView ItemValue;

            ItemValue = (TextView) vi.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            ItemValue.setText(ItemValue[position]);
            return (vi);
        }
    }
```

Please help me to how to set a items value and how to get the listview values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Want] to get the the values of all the items on click of the button

To get *all* values, create a method `getAllValues()` inside `PassengerListUpdate`:

```
public String[] getAllValues() {
    return ItemValue;
}
```

Declare your adapter globally:

```
PassengerListUpdate myAdapter;
```

Initialize it in `showPassengerListView(String[])`:

```
myAdapter = new PassengerListUpdate(passengerList);
listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

To get the list of all values on button click:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (myAdapter != null) {
            String[] allValues = myAdapter.getAllValues();
        }

    }
});
```

> I want to update the items value on click of button

To update the values, you can simply reinitialize and set `myAdapter`:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myAdapter = new PassengerListUpdate(updatedPassengerList);
        listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: i want to update particular item of the listview and i have the postion of the item

Comment: @User If you need to update a particular item, use the position => `passengerList[position] = newString;`. After this => `listView.setAdapter(new PassengerListUpdate(passengerList));`.

Comment: @thanks vikram i was stucked in this from last 2 days thanks alot for the help ...

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to get whole the values inside ListView. You can get number of item in adapter, and then get value one by one by its position.

```
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    final int count = mMyAdapter.getCount();
    for( int i = 0; i < count; ++i ){
        String item = mMyAdapter.getItem(i);
        results.add(item);
    }
    return results;
```

Second, in order to add or update the value of ListView, in general extending [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) is much easier than implementing BaseAdapter, because of ArrayAdapter support add / remove / insert method by itself. For example,

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View vi;
        vi = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
        TextView ItemValue;

        ItemValue = (TextView) vi.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        ItemValue.setText(ItemValue[position]);
        return (vi);
    }
}
```

And you can updating adapter's value quiet directly,

```
mMyAdapter.add("Add Item");
mMyAdapter.remove("Remove Item");
mMyAdapter.insert("Insert Item", 0);
```

After finishing the jobs, you can call adapter's notifyDatSetChanged() method in order to update the UI, and I think this is more efficient way than setting up the new adapter every time whenever data is updated.

```
mMyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i want to update a single item of the listview at a time .i have position of the item